# Spawn a command block with a player's name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a command block with a button.
When clicking the button the command block should clear himself and spawn three new command blocks.
But here is the tricky part the new command blocks should have the name of the player who pressed the button.
Basically when the players name is Dinnerbone the new command blocks should have the command:

```
/tp @p[name=Dinnerbone] ~ ~1 ~-3
```

When the player who presses the button is named Notch the command of the new command blocks should be:

```
/tp @p[name=Notch] ~ ~1 ~-3
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: The closest you could get is by this command, i think: `/say /tp @ p[name=@p] ~ ~1 ~-3` or something simmilar :D

Comment: Automatically placing the name of the player in a command block isn't possible, but you should be able to do what you want with scoreboard tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible right now (1.9.4).

What you can do, is give the player a tag: (Put this command block behind the button)

```
/scoreboard players tag @p add THEONE
```

Then (in repeating command block) put the command you want to execute:

```
/tp @a[tag=THEONE] ~ ~1 ~
```

Append your commands into Chain-command-blocks.
Append a Chain-Command-block put this command:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=THEONE] remove THEONE
```

To reset the machine.

The setup:

[image]

Hope it helped (:

Comment: This might actually help me. I have to infestigate the whole scoreboard thing a little bit more.

Comment: @Eydamos: The `scoreboard` is a very important tool in a command blocker's toolbox.  It forms the basis of a lot of contraptions.  It, along with `execute` are the two commands that you should really study and familiarize yourself with, because you'll use them a lot.  They are the general purpose commands that are used to make everything else work.